# Flask returns FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, api, file, flask, error-handling

I have a Flask app that uploads files to AWS S3

This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work and it's puzzling me:

```
@app.route('/upload',methods=['post'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        diag_file = request.files['file']
        if diag_file:
            filename = secure_filename(diag_file.filename)
            result = create_presigned_post("bucket123", filename)
            #Open file and load it
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                files = {'file': (filename, f)}
                http_response = requests.post(result['url'], data=result['fields'], files=files)
            # If successful, returns HTTP status code 204
            logging.info(f'File upload HTTP status code: {http_response.status_code}')
            msg = str(create_presigned_url("bucket123", filename))
                
    return render_template("file_upload_to_s3.html",msg =msg)
```

I am getting the proverbial `FileNotFoundError`

Error Message: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'`

Full Error Trace:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2021 15:25:50] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/test_user/dev/s3upload/app.py", line 100, in upload
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

How can I make sure that the file exists?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Please update the question to include the _whole_ error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon - Updated with full error spill

Comment: I don't see any code that would ensure `filename` exists.  How is it created?

Comment: @JohnGordon - I'm consulting the official file upload docs. Maybe this could help you help me: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: I don't understand.  If that file is being uploaded, then it doesn't exist (yet) as a local file.  Why are you trying to open it for reading?

Comment: @JohnGordon the file exists locally and is to be uploaded to aws s3

Comment: Again, I don't understand.  You say the file exists, and yet the error clearly says that it does not.  `open()` is looking in the current directory for the file -- are you sure that's where it is?

Comment: `filename` is the name of the file uploaded in the request.      The file exists on the user's computer, but it does not (yet) exist on the server.  It's your job to extract the file contents from the request and save it on the server, and you haven't done that.  So I have to ask again -- why are you expecting the file to exist locally?